# Sharing on Facebook is sometimes working fine and sometimes not (no title, no description, no thumbnail)

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I'm working at Storify and we have an issue when we want to share some stories on Facebook.
We are using og meta tags to make sure the story is shareable in a nice way. Mainly, we use og:title, og:site_name, og:type, og:url, og:image and og:description.

For some stories, it works like a charm and it looks terrific, e.g. http://storify.com/elevour/smog-attacks-beijing-yet-again

[image: Working]

But some stories, it doesn't work at all, e.g. http://storify.com/documentally/40-at-40

[image: Not working]

We use the same script for both, and OpenGraph.in can detect my og meta tags on every single story... http://www.opengraph.in/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstorify.com%2Fdocumentally%2F40-at-40&format=html

Do you have an idea what it can be?
Is it a bug from Facebook?

Comment: Kudos for Storify by the way, both technically, and UX, it's simply great

Answer (score 3):

Vinch, I'm getting quite inconsistent results when I run these links through the facebook debugger ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstorify.com%2Fdocumentally%2F40-at-40 ) it seems to have trouble parsing the urls. For the beijing link, it did successfully parse it the first time, but has returned an error on all subsequent tries, for the 40 link I get an error every time. Perhaps this has something to do with the way you're resolving urls on your server? When I run a user's url eg: http://storify.com/documentally/ through the debugger, it returns the generic og data from http://storify.com/ ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The 40 link was working... But only once. No changes on our side. I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the facebook cache and solution is to refresh the facebook cache by going to the link. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

and pressing the button "Fetch New Scrape information".

Hope it helps